# Error when adding reference Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I clicking "Add reference" for a project I get an error that says "Operation could not be completed". I get the error for all projects in my solution. When I trying och a PCL I also get "Specifified cast is not valid". How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A repair of Visual Studio fixed the problem.